# backup and restoration of my C drive only

Tags: windows, backup, clonezilla

I bought a dell laptop with 1 tb internal hardisk drive. I made 3 partitions in my hardrive and all having data like movies, songs and document.

Now I want to take the backup of my C drive only with clonezilla, but most of the tutorials I watched in the youtube taking the backup as image of whole harddrive instead of single partition.

I have huge data in my other partitions and I think if I take the backup of whole hardrive it will backup of all unnecessary data. I want to backup my Windows and applications only. please guide me

Answer (score 0):

Clonezilla is a great tool, but its main purpose is to clone - not to back up.  There are many free products out there that is designed to do back-up, but the solution I use at home is to have a batch file which copies all my important folders to a network share.  You could modify this to copy to a USB disk, or to a second hard drive.

```
@echo off
::: Begin set date

for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/-. " %%i in ('date /t') do (call :set_date %%i %%j %%k %%l)
goto :end_set_date

:set_date
if "%1:~0,1%" gtr "9" shift
for /f "skip=1 tokens=2-4 delims=(-)" %%m in ('echo,^|date') do (set %%m=%1&set %%n=%2&set %%o=%3)
goto :eof

:end_set_date
::: End set date

echo "Backing up Users"
robocopy c:\users\%username% z:\Backup\%computername%\%yy%%mm%%dd%\Users\%username% /xd "Application Data" "DropBox" /s /r:0 /XJD /XJF

echo "Backing up Stuff"
robocopy c:\stuff z:\Backup\%computername%\%yy%%mm%%dd%\stuff /xd "Application Data" "cache" /s /r:0 /XJD /XJF

echo Back up of %yy%%mm%%dd% Finished!

pause
```

Modify as your needs require

If your intention however is to back up the C: Drive so that you can roll back the entire volume - then use a product such as EaseUS Todo Backup Free 9.0.  I am in no way affiliated with EaseUS, and this is not an advertisement.

Answer (score 0):

Get yourself a WinPE disk and use DISM to capture your `C:\` as a `.wim` file. This will capture (and preserve attributes and permissions) the data in the partition only and you can then restore it later (after re-creating the partition) or open the WIM to extract individual files later, again, using DISM (or, for quick access, I often use 7-Zip as that now has .wim extraction capabilities).